# Android EditText data entry in lowercase determined at runtime

Tags: android, android-edittext, lowercase

I was rather surprised that this was not a native function of `EditText`, but I can't find any mechanism that will convert inputs to lower case as they are entered into an `EditText` field. The `EditText` field determines whether to be lowercase at runtime, so I can't have this in the XML, it needs to be fired as I allocate the `EditText`. I have tried:

1) Negating the ALL Caps:

```
 mEntry.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |  ~InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS);
```

2) Creating a listener:

private TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    if (!Utilities.stringIsBlank(mField.getFormat()) && Field.LOWER.equalsIgnoreCase(mField.getFormat())) {
        if (!Utilities.stringIsBlank(s.toString()) && !s.toString().equals(s.toString().toLowerCase()) ) {
            mEntry.setText(s.toString().toLowerCase());
            mEntry.setSelection(start+1);
        }
    }
}
```

}

The problem with this is that when I call the `setText()` it recursively calls back to the `onTextChange` event, which messes with the location of cursor, depending on what it is changing.

Anyone have a simple solution that I have somehow missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a filter.  Below is a modified [AllCaps filter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.AllCaps.html) to convert everything to lowercase in stead of uppercase.

```
/**
 * This filter will lower case all the capitalized letters that are added
 * through edits.
 */
public static class NoCapsFilter implements InputFilter {

    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
        Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(source.charAt(i))) {
                char[] v = new char[end - start];
                TextUtils.getChars(source, start, end, v, 0);
                String s = new String(v).toLowerCase();

                if (source instanceof Spanned) {
                    SpannableString sp = new SpannableString(s);
                    TextUtils.copySpansFrom((Spanned) source,
                                            start, end, null, sp, 0);
                    return sp;
                }
                else {
                    return s;
                }
            }
        }

        return null; // keep original
    }
}
```

Then just set the filter on your `EditText`.

```
mEntry.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new NoCapsFilter()});
```

Comment: Will this affect any inputs I may be setting with the mEntry.setInputType()? Such as   if (mField.getNoSpellCheck())
   inputType = (inputType | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);

Comment: Absolutely brilliant, works like a charm. Wish I could upvote it a 100 times! thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked for you!  It shouldn't affect the inputType stuff.  If the EditText already has some filters, you can get them with the `getFilters()` method, make a new array that adds your new filter to the current ones, and then call `setFilters(...)` with that array.

Comment: No other filters that I know of, but good to know that for the future. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Check the text inside your if statement like this

**`if(mEntry.getText().toString().equals( mEntry.getText().toString().toLowerCase() )
return;`**

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    if (!Utilities.stringIsBlank(mField.getFormat()) && Field.LOWER.equalsIgnoreCase(mField.getFormat())) {
        if (!Utilities.stringIsBlank(s.toString()) && !s.toString().equals(s.toString().toLowerCase()) ) {
if (mEntry.getText().toString().equals(mEntry.getText().toString().toLowerCase())return;
            mEntry.setText(s.toString().toLowerCase());
            mEntry.setSelection(start+1);
        }
    }
}
```